# RxJava map observable differently once another completable completes

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to get my head around something in RxJava. I am subscribing to a Realm changeset Observable while also making a request via Retrofit, so subscribing to a Completable for that. What I want to happen is to wrap the result of the changeset Observable in an object that has a flag set to one value before the Retrofit Completable completes, and a different value after it either completes or errors. I've tried this via a merge but it doesn't seem right at all, as I'd have to convert the completable to an observable and emit a Boolean or something. Does anyone know of a way to get this sort of behaviour in RxJava?

Comment: Could you describe what you want to accomplish rather than how you want to accomplish it? Without code to look at, we can't help very much.

Comment: That's a good point, that wasnt a very well put question. What I want to achieve is to subscribe to changes in a Realm query, and also reload the data (via a GET request through Retrofit). I want to show a loading spinner the first time the request is made (when there is no offline data to show) but if there is data in Realm then show this immediately. There is also a 'no data available' view that should be shown if a request has been made but has come back with an empty array. I might rethink my question and post a new one with example code, I was tired and frustrated when I posted this one.